# Локальные переменные функции, JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Создаются ли новые экземпляры при вызовах одной и той же функции, или они одни и те же?
То есть, например, если в этом коде g() выполнится уже после второго вызова f(), то будет ли новый вызов влиять на переменную "a", как ее видит функция g()?

```js
function f(value) {
  var a = value;
  somePromise().then(() => {
                     ...
                     g();
                });
}
                     
                     
f(1);
f(5);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для каждого вызова function f() будет существовать своя локальная переменная a, которая попадет в контекст замыкания:

```js
function g(a) {
  document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += 'g(' + a + ')<br />';
}

function f(value) {
  var a = value;

  setTimeout(() => {
    g(a);
  }, 500);
}

f(1);
f(5);
```

```html
<p id='log'></p>
```